# How to render 2d text or 2d image in webgl?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

When i try to render the image or text using the context of Canvas 2d. I'm getting the cross-origin error. even if i made crossorigin ='anonymous' it is behaving wierd. Can anyone help me out. here is my code.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The image element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded.
>       at Image.image.onload (file:///C:/Users/***/WebGl-Integration/texture.html:312:8)

Reference :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Using_textures_in_WebGL

```
function loadTexture(gl, url) {
  const texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // Because images have to be download over the internet
  // they might take a moment until they are ready.
  // Until then put a single pixel in the texture so we can
  // use it immediately. When the image has finished downloading
  // we'll update the texture with the contents of the image.
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const width = 1;
  const height = 1;
  const border = 0;
  const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
  const pixel = new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]);  // opaque blue
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
                width, height, border, srcFormat, srcType,
                pixel);

  const image = new Image();
  image.src="img_the_scream.jpg";
  //image.crossOrigin="Anonymous";
  image.onload = function() {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

     **getting issue here**

    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
                  srcFormat, srcType, image);

    // WebGL1 has different requirements for power of 2 images
    // vs non power of 2 images so check if the image is a
    // power of 2 in both dimensions.
    if (isPowerOf2(image.width) && isPowerOf2(image.height)) {
       // Yes, it's a power of 2. Generate mips.
       gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    } else {
       // No, it's not a power of 2. Turn of mips and set
       // wrapping to clamp to edge
       gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
       gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
       gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    }
  };
  image.src = url;

  return texture;
}

function isPowerOf2(value) {
  return (value & (value - 1)) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run a simple web server. You can not load images into WebGL from your hard drive directly.

- [Here's one with a GUI](https://greggman.github.io/servez/).
- [Here's another](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en)
- [Here's one that runs from the command line](https://github.com/greggman/servez-cli)

See [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-setup-and-installation.html) and [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html) as well

Comment: To learn WEBGL do we need to learn OPENGL (GLSL)? Because i'm very new to WEBGL and canvas

Comment: No, you can [learn WebGL directly here](https://webglfundamentals.org)